# How do i force vlc when buffering occurs to play live content instead of continuing where it stopped

Tags: vlc-media-player, http, mpeg

I'm playing MPEG-TS stream over http, sometimes buffering occurs due to connection problems, in order not to get live delay, how do i force vlc to play the stream at the same timestamp if it did not buffer?